# SOA with asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know that asp.net MVC supports webservices call,

But I am asking in a wide scope that I have developed MVC application and I want to build an ERP that Integrates both asp.net 2005 application and my own MVC application.

So is it possible?
I am just an infant to think like this.

And this question comes in my mind when I saw a first video of webcast of WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I would build service calls (WCF, REST etc... what ever you are comfortable with) for your ERP. Once you have that your ASP.NET app can call them and so can your MVC app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - might need some modification of the asp.net app to include web service layer.

i would watch the MVC Storefront series http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/#MVCStorefrontStarterKit

for some tips on structuring the application and repository+ pattern